# "Uncaught Error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM"

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, heroku

I don't have the following error when I run my code on my VirtualBox. (localhost)

But when I deploy on Heroku (and run heroku open or heroku local web) I got whole blank page, and the following error: bundle.js:1285 Uncaught Error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.

[Image of Detailed Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ey5ou.jpg)

My react versions in the package.json

...

```
"react": "^0.14.3",

"react-dom": "^0.14.3",

"react-redux": "4.3.0",

"react-router": "^4.1.2",

"react-router-dom": "^4.1.2",
```

I have no idea about this error and have googled some similar error on the stackoverflow. Most of solutions are putting bundle.js before the end of the body.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title> Drone Tracker </title>
    </head>

    <body>
          <div id="wrapper" class="active">
            <div id="page-content-wrapper">
                <div class="page-content-inset">
                  <div id="root"> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAGD352Uy7zH5XMLZ__x2XyuMyUOxVDLgQ&language=zh-TW"></script>
        <script src="/bundle.js"> </script>
    </body>  
</html>
```

index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ContentBody from './components/content_body';
import NavBar from './components/NavBar.js';
import Main from './components/Main.js';
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class App extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <NavBar />
                <Main />
            </div>
        );
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter >
            <App />
    </BrowserRouter>, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

Main.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

import Home from './Home.js';
import ContentBody from './content_body';

const Main = () => (
  <main>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
      <Route path='/contentBody' component={ContentBody}/>
    </Switch>
  </main>
);

export default Main;
```

Home.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>HOME PAGE</h1>
  </div>
);

export default Home;
```

Comment: try logging `document.querySelector('#root')` check whether it returns a single DOM element or an array of it.

Comment: @abdul I try 'root' but it can't work. (whole blank even on my localhost page)
I use '#root', you can see this page https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp

Comment: @JefreeSujit I got <div id="root"> </div> when I log on the heroku page.